# Text not showing up in CSS dropdown menu - IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having an issue with a dropdown menu in IE8. Everything looks OK on Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8, more precisely the text from the dropdown menu doesn't show up. What am I missing?

This is the website: http://stuffforyourdog.com/maxabiz/collegeadvisors/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the use of Cufon plugin. I copied your html/css in jsfiddle and it works on all IE/Chrome/FF. http://jsfiddle.net/t6sqV/ I suggest dropping cufon, and use a service like Typekit instead: https://typekit.com/ . You can also use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to download fonts ready to be used using only CSS.

ps: be careful. hover on non link elements does not work for IE6.

Comment: Thanks, removing cufon solved the problem. 

I had a hunch it was that cufon thingy but not enough to actually see what happens if I removed it.